# Export datas from DB to HTML?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

i'm working on a library DB, exporting datas from an host DB to display them into a table(HTML/CSS classes) but it reports php code in the table-cell:

[image: Acutally display table]

I inserted the following codes(HTML/PHP):

```
<!--DATA PAGE-->


<div id="datas">

<?php

 # Init the MySQL Connection
  if( !( $db = mysql_connect( 'database' ) ) )
    die( 'Failed to connect to MySQL Database Server - #'.mysql_errno().': '.mysql_error();
  if( !mysql_select_db( 'ram' ) )
    die( 'Connected to Server, but Failed to Connect to Database - #'.mysql_errno().': '.mysql_error();

 # Prepare the INSERT Query
  $insertTPL = 'INSERT INTO `TITOLO` VALUES( "%s" , "%s" , "%s" , "%s" )';
  $insertSQL = sprintf( $insertTPL ,
                 mysql_real_escape_string( $TITOLO ) ,
                 mysql_real_escape_string( $AUTORE ) ,
                 mysql_real_escape_string( $EDITORE ) ,
                 mysql_real_escape_string( $ANNO ) ,
                 mysql_real_escape_string( $#ID ) );

 # Execute the INSERT Query
  if( !( $insertRes = mysql_query( $insertSQL ) ) ){

    <div class="tbook" align="center">
          <div class="tr">
           <div class="td">TITOLO</div>
           <div class="td">AUTORE</div>
           <div class="td">EDITORE</div>
           <div class="td">ANNO</div>
           <div class="td">#ID</div>
          </div>
<?php

   while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $selectRes ) ){
   echo 
       "<div class="tr">
          <div class="td">{$row['TITOLO'\]}</div>
          <div class="td">{$row['AUTORE'\]}</div>
          <div class="td">{$row['EDITORE'\]}</div>
          <div class="td">{$row['ANNO'\]}</div>
          <div class="td">{$row['#ID'\]}</div>
       </div> \n"; 
   }
?>

  </div>

<?php mysql_close($connector); ?>

</div>
```

**Note:** Host DB queries works OK but PHP code won't load datas for display them in my table.

https://jsfiddle.net/krzv2wkq/2/ show how actually works(missing datas from DB)

Comment: can you make a fiddle example with fake db data?

Comment: @JarlikStepsto jsfiddle update in question

Comment: still dont got, what is wrong. How should it looks like and what is happening now? please define your problem more clear

Comment: HTML display SQL query into the table and CSS class won't work as it is defined to(example: i write "background-color:red;" but it display transparent with no margin left etc etc...)

Comment: do you have a link to your page? https://jsfiddle.net/krzv2wkq/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am getting a hard time to relate your code in your question.

1. Why are you using "**INSERT**" in the first place when you are trying to fetch data from DB and display it on the table?
2. You can't display your table inside `<?php ?>` you have to use **echo** the `<div>` part.
3. I don't get the line: `if( !( $insertRes = mysql_query( $insertSQL ) ) ){` What are you trying to do here if the return is true?

**EDIT:**

I'm not sure if you are trying to **output the data from your db table into your html table**, but I think this is what you are trying to achieve. If so, you can give this code a shot.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM your_table_here";
$result = mysql_query($sql); //execute query

while($arr = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ //Fetch query
    $TITOLO = mysql_real_escape_string($arr['TITOLO']);
    $AUTORE = mysql_real_escape_string($arr['AUTORE']);
    $EDITORE = mysql_real_escape_string($arr['EDITORE']);
    $ANNO = mysql_real_escape_string($arr['ANNO']);
    $ID = mysql_real_escape_string($arr['ID']);

    echo "
        <div class='tbook' align='center'>
          <div class='tr'>
           <div class='td'>$TITOLO</div>
           <div class='td'>$AUTORE</div>
           <div class='td'>$EDITORE</div>
           <div class='td'>$ANNO</div>
           <div class='td'>$ID</div>
          </div>
        </div>
    ";
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm trying to insert datas into arrays and then add them into table if queries values are OK. Most of lines code are part of old programming(and a big part of my actually issue).

Comment: So the data flow looks like this From  **DB -> Arrays -> Table output**? Am i getting it right? And btw you are missing a `}` of the line `if( !( $insertRes = mysql_query( $insertSQL ) ) ){` and a closing php tag `?>`

Comment: This is the method i need to create the output by using PHP but this question is, at the moment, not useful anymore.

Comment: Can you perhaps show us the structure of your database table at least?

Comment: Whay you mean? SQL exports or the table rows?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you close the open `<?php` tag with an `?>` before the HTML section, otherwise it won't be rendered correctly.

Comment: After these two lines
`# Execute the INSERT Query
  if( !( $insertRes = mysql_query( $insertSQL ) ) ){`

There is a `?>` missing.